# How to add commands to the target line of your Putty shortcut

Tags: shortcuts, putty

I was able to create a shortcut on my desktop for Putty by using the ***"file path" -load  -l  -pw***  format. My question is: Can there be more commands added to the end of that so that I can access different directories or run a script automatically?

If so, what are the commands, like -load, -l and -pw, for running scripts and, for example, changing directories?

Answer (score 1):

First for putty documentation see:  http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/puttydoc.txt

This will tell you all the command line arguments supported by Putty.

If you want shortcuts for things, you are probably going to have to create *.bat files and then specify a shortcut on your desktop for it.  The *.bat file can contain windows commands, but remember each program has different options available.